# How to get average of all numbers (not a group) in hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table, and I wish to add a column which is the average of all lines (not by group).

For example, the table is like:

```
  name    num
   a      1
   b      2
```

I wish to get:

```
  name    num   avg_num
   a      1     1.5
   b      2     1.5
```

I tried this:

```
select name, num, avg(num) 
from table 
group by name, num
```

However, it returns

```
  name    num   avg_num
   a      1     1
   b      2     2
```

So how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify an empty window (which covers the whole table)

```
select name, num, avg(num) over() as avg_num from table;
```